# Is it possible to create a Firefox WebExtension that changes about:config settings? How?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I would like to create a WebExtension that provides toggle buttons for some of the settings in `about:config` (e.g. `permissions.default.image`).

- Is it possible to do this in WebExtensions?
- If so, what is the API?

---

I belive that this question predates WebExtensions: [A Firefox extension that changes a value in the about:config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157173/a-firefox-extension-that-changes-a-value-in-the-aboutconfig)

This question is actually about print dialogs: [Is it possible to set config settings on Firefox from a Addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809432/is-it-possible-to-set-config-settings-on-firefox-from-a-addon)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible. Your best bet is to open a page informing your users of what they need to do in order to use your extension.

A limited amount of preferences is available in browserSettings and privacy.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserSettings
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/privacy

You could also write a native messaging program which changes the preferences on disk level. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging

Comment: Not only `browserSettings`, but also [`privacy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/privacy) provides [`BrowserSetting`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/types/BrowserSetting) objects.